# Linux Red Hat fails to mount encrypted USB stick in exec mode

Tags: usb-flash-drive, mount, redhat-enterprise-linux

I'm having trouble with an encrypted USB stick. In order to view the encrypted partition, software on the stick must be executed, but as soon as the stick is plugged in, it is mounted with executable permissions turned off, so nothing on the stick can be run - even by root.

Note that this is not the case on our Fedora Linux workstations, where we have created an entry in the sudoers file to allow users to run the login/logout programs.

Is there a simple way of changing this behaviour for all users? I need a solution which does NOT assume the individual users have root access, or that the stick will always be inserted into the same USB port.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Any particular reason why you aren't just using LUKS?

Comment: These USB sticks are company approved and are used to transfer files between non-networked Windows and Linux workstations.

Comment: [Well, okay...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeOTFE)

Comment: Sorry, replacing the encryption scheme is not an option.